# Golang, running for range loop on channel, how to continue execution of block having received next value from channel?

Tags: go, parallel-processing, channel

I'm studying Golang and now I'm stuck with a such situation.
Let's say I have a channel on ints:
`ints = make(chan int)`
And I keep receiving values after some period of time. So I'm running for range loop on my channel:

```
for update := range ints {
    if update > 10 { // let's say update == 15 for example
         // Here I want to continue execution of this block, however having
         // the next value of update var, even though it will be <= 10. 
         // lets say next value is received and update == 5.
         fmt.Println(update) // So this should print "5", not "10"
         continue
    } else {
         fmt.Println("less than 10")
         continue
    }
}
```

So basically I want this block to sleep for some time until next value is received from channel and continue execution, given that update variable now has different value.

My first thoughts were to create smth like "isNewValueReceived" bool variable and use it to continue execution where I want. However, it seems to be wrong solution, since the logic of the program might get more complex.

Please, help me to find a solution of this problem. Thank you in advance!

UPD:

```
hasGoneAbove := false // initially set to false as no values have been received
hasGoneAbove2 := false
hasGoneAbove3 := false
hasGoneAbove3 := false
for update := range ints {
    if hasGoneAbove{
      doSomeJob()
      hasGoneAbove = false
      hasGoneAbove2 = true
      continue
    }
    if hasGoneAbove2{
      doSomeJob2()
      hasGoneAbove2 = false
      hasGoneAbove3 = true
      continue
    }
    if hasGoneAbove3{
      doSomeJob3()
      hasGoneAbove3 = false
      continue
    }
    if update > 10 { 
         hasGoneAbove = true
    } else {
         fmt.Println("less than 10")
    }
}
```

Comment: "I want to continue execution of this if block, given that after some time channel receives new value and update variable now holds some different value." I cannot make any sense of this.

Comment: lets say i received update == 15. "if update > 10" block now starts executing. next what i want to do is to make that block sleep for some time until channel receives new value. after new value is received, i want to continue executing that block. Slightly changed my code above, so I hope now it is clear what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to make sense of your question, you seem to want to work with a state tracking variable:

```golang
hasGoneAbove := false // initially set to false as no values have been received
for update := range ints {
    if hasGoneAbove{
      fmt.Println(update)
      hasGoneAbove = false
    }
    if update > 10 { 
         hasGoneAbove = true
    } else {
         fmt.Println("less than 10")
    }
}
```

Updated:
With this sort of holding only the last value in memory:

```golang
var lastValue int // use zero value
for update := range ints {
    if lastValue > 2{
      doSomeJob2()
    }
    if hasGoneAbove > 3{
      doSomeJob3()
    }
    if lastValue > 10{
      doSomeJob()
    } else {
       fmt.Println("less than 10")
    }
    lastValue = update
}
```

Note: as per the code in your question, if the LastValue is `10` then all three functions are going to execute. Depending on how compute intensive they are you might want to run them in a goroutine.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Is this correct handling of such situation, by simply using "flags"? I thought this should be slightly harder by using some goroutines or maybe by creating another channel... Not sure since I'm only studying this :)))

Comment: Well it really depends what you want to do. If you need to do asynchronous processing or do not want to block reading the channel, yes you'll probably  got with a goroutine based solution but from your question that did not seem to be the case.

Comment: in my case this is gonna be a bit deeper. i would need to define hasGoneAbove2 and set it to true in "if hasGoneAbove" block, define has goneAbove3 and set to true in a "if hasGoneAbove2" block and so on up until 10 of such blocks. Would you still recommend to simply define 10 flags and 10 different blocks on the same level inside the for loop?

Comment: Could you edit your question to give a better understanding of your problem in that case as there seems to be more logic to integrate. Also include how computationally intensive each operation is/may be as that will have a great impact in the decision